# type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'List<ternakModel> in a type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I have problem in the emulator android. type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'List in a type cast. I can't solve of this. I use provider ListBuilder. so I'm retrieving data using the provider in the form of a list. Can you help?

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TernakProvider ternakProvider = Provider.of<TernakProvider>(context);
    return Consumer<TernakProvider>(
        builder: (context, providerData, _) => FutureBuilder(
            future: providerData.getTernak(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
                return Text("Loading...");
              }
              List<ternakModel> ternak = snapshot.data as List<ternakModel>;
```

and this is file provider

```
class TernakProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<ternakModel> _ternak = [];
  List<ternakModel> get ternak => _ternak;
  set ternak(List<ternakModel> ternak) {
    _ternak = ternak;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<bool> getTernak() async {
    try {
      List<ternakModel> ternak = await TernakService().getTernak();
      _ternak = ternak;
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my service file

```
class TernakService {
  String baseUrl = "BaseURL";

  Future getTernak() async {
    var url = Uri.parse("$baseUrl/api/ternak");
    var response = await http.get(url);
    print(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data']['list'];
      List<ternakModel> ternak = [];

      for (var item in data) {
        ternak.add(ternakModel.fromJson(item));
      }

      return ternak;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Gagal Get Ternak');
    }
  }
}
```

this is listview code

```
body: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: ternak.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Center(
                            child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          const DetailTernak(),
                                      settings: RouteSettings(
                                        arguments:
                                            ternak[index].id_ternak.toString(),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },

                                // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 0.5,
                                // margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                                child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                          width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .width /
                                              1.2,
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                              left: 16,
                                              right: 16,
                                              top: 10,
                                              bottom: 10),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                            border: Border.all(
                                              color: const Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                              width: 1,
                                            ),
                                            boxShadow: [
                                              BoxShadow(
                                                blurStyle: BlurStyle.outer,
                                                color: Colors.black
                                                    .withOpacity(0.1),
                                                spreadRadius: 0,
                                                blurRadius: 8,
                                                offset: const Offset(0,
                                                    0), // changes position of shadow
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          child: Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Row(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .spaceBetween,
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Container(
                                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          left: 15, top: 15),
                                                      child: Row(
                                                        children: [
                                                          Text(
                                                            "ID   ",
                                                            style: regular
                                                                .copyWith(
                                                              color: Color(
                                                                  0xFF646464),
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                          Text(
                                                            "${ternak[index].id_ternak}",
                                                            style: semibold,
                                                          )
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ]),
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your getTernak inside TernakProvider to this:

```
Future<List<ternakModel>> getTernak() async {
    try {
      List<ternakModel> ternak = await TernakService().getTernak();
      _ternak = ternak;
      return ternak;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return [];
    }
  }
```

Comment: My listview is not showing, is there an error in my code? because I am not find error

Comment: could you include listview code?

Comment: I already update listview code

Comment: could you include result of print("data = $data"); after define data inside getTernak in TernakService class?